# Calling function on parent element give 'super' keyword unexpected here

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a typical call hierarchy

```
class A
{
   mirm(){
     //stuff here
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   constructor(){
     //obtain a promise
     promise().then(this.setUp)
   }

   setUp(){
    super.mirm();
   }
}
```

Could it be that the promise might be doing something to the scope? I would actually expect for you to be able to do something like `this.mirm()` from the `setUp` function since it should just follow the prototype chain. What gives? I am compiling with babel and have es2015 as target.

Comment: You [shouldn't do this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) anyway .-)

Comment: Well I was not returning a promise, but the logic of not executing any tasks inside the constructor does make sense. I have changed it now, however the problem would have persisted regardless so my question still holds, thanks though.

Comment: unless you have a better design pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `this.setUp` detaches the current context object from the function reference when it gets invoked, therefore the `this` in the `super`'s method is confused about where to look

Consider wrapping it instead

```
// arrow function preserves context
foo.then(() => this.setUp());
// OR
// binding it to explicitly give context
foo.then(this.setUp.bind(this));
```

Comment: Yep, arrow functions did the trick for me, I read they have lexical scope and was just coming back to answer my question. I was unaware of the second approach though, thanks.

Comment: `super` is functioning well in unbound functions, it looks up `mirm` correctly. The problem is only that it calls it on the wrong `this`, so `mirm` itself will be confused.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I'll reword it